# Copy rows (not entire row) from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with the below code. "Backend" is the Source Sheet and "Availability" is the Target sheet. Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub CopyA()

Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long
lr = Sheets("Backend").Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = Sheets("Availability").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = lr To 2 Step -1
        If Range("Backend!AB" & r).Value = "A" Then
           Range("Availability!A" & lr2 + 1 & ":C" & lr2 + 1) = 
           Range("Backend!V" & r & ":X" & r).Value2
           lr2 = Sheets("Availability").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you getting an error with the code or incorrect output? Please be more specific on how you need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code I think you are trying to copy columns `V:X` from sheet `Backend` if column `AB` = `A` and paste the data into column A of sheet `Availability`.

This code achieves that:

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim lastRow As Long, rw As Long

    lastRow = Sheets("Backend").Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row

    With Worksheets("Backend")
        For rw = lastRow To 2 Step -1
            If .Range("AB" & rw) = "A" Then
                pasteRow = Worksheets("Availability").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Range("V" & rw & ":X" & rw).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Availability").Range("A" & pasteRow & ":C" & pasteRow)
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

In your original code you are looping backwards with `Step -1`. A consequence of this is that the data pasted into `Availability` will be in reverse order. If you want the pasted data to appear in the order it is found on `backend` then use this code instead:

```
Sub CopyData2()
    Dim copyRng As Range, cl As Range

    Set copyRng = Worksheets("Backend").Range("AB2:AB" & Worksheets("Backend").Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row)

    With Worksheets("Availability")
        For Each cl In copyRng
            If cl = "A" Then
                pasteRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Worksheets("Backend").Range("V" & cl.Row & ":X" & cl.Row).Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & pasteRow & ":C" & pasteRow)
            End If
        Next cl
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Alex, Thanks a lot for the help! Apologies for not clearly mentioning as what the code was for!  Is there any way we can paste those columns as values (instead of formulas) in the 'Availability' tab??

Comment: You can do this:  Worksheets("Backend").Range("V" & cl.Row & ":X" & cl.Row).Copy  .Range("A" & pasteRow & ":C" & pasteRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The code worked superb. I just removed the '.' before the Range where we are pasting the values. Thanks a lot you saved a lot of time.